# How can I get a human-readable description from a signal number?

Tags: c, string, posix, signals

Does the POSIX standard or another C standard provide a way to recover a meaningful message from a signal number, in the same way that `strerror()` makes it possible to recover a message from `errno`? The Gnu C library has `strsignal()`, but if possible, I would like something portable to BSD and other Unix variants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, interestingly, there is a standard way to get a string message from a signal in POSIX. It is, quite coincidentally, [`strsignal()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strsignal.html).  From POSIX.1-2008:

> The strsignal() function shall map the signal number in signum to an implementation-defined string and shall return a pointer to it. It shall use the same set of messages as the psignal() function.

An environment that does not provide you this function is not POSIX-compliant.  Although relatively new (Issue 7 came out in 2008), I have a man page for `strsignal()` on [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strsignal.3.html), so that's a good sign.

Comment: Thanks: http://tinyurl.com/d4z9ev

The GNU man page, which says "This function is not part of any standard", obviously needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

The externally defined array `sys_siglist` contains the signal descriptions for each signal number, and is standard issue on BSD.

```
#include <signal.h>

extern const char *const sys_siglist[];
```