# Copying Bash's signal termination messages

Tags: c, shell, signals

Right now I'm making a program that is supposed to mimic how Bash operates with signals. Is there a more efficient way of printing to the terminal signal termination messages (like "segmentation fault", "Illegal instruction", "Alarm clock", etc.)? Because right now what I have in my mind is just a long, long series of if/else if statements to cater to each signal.

```
   if((WIFSIGNALED(status) && ((WTERMSIG(status) != SIGINT)))){

      ...

      else if(/*signal == 7*/){
         fprintf(stderr, "Bus error");
      }

      else if(/*signal == 8*/){
         fprintf(stderr, "Floating point exception");
      }

      ...

      if(/*signal == 11*/){
         fprintf(stderr, "segmentation fault ");
      }

      ...
}
```

It just seems like this is trying to use brute force.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719481/how-can-i-get-a-human-readable-description-from-a-signal-number/1719492#1719492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `strsignal` from the `string.h` header or `psignal` from `signal.h`. Read their man pages for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the original description as-is, use @ZanLynx's solution.

Otherwise, in general and/or if you need to tweak the messages for some reason: a usual way to replace a `if/else if` chain or `switch` is to create a table for which the index corresponds to the condition, i.e.:

```
const char * messages[] = {
    ...
    "Bus error",
    "Floating point exception",
    "Segmentation fault",
    ...
};
```

Then, you replace the original code with:

```
fprintf(stderr, messages[signal]);
```

Comment: Awesome. This answer will actually give me a higher quality of life in coding. I never thought of doing something like that.

Comment: for extra quality of life you could even use `const char *messages[] = {...}`

Comment: @Lazarus: Replacing code with data structures? Yes, it is a good thing to learn. And `strsignal` does that in the C library: the  man page mentions it uses an array named `sys_siglist`. But you should use the function.

Comment: @wildplasser: Indeed!